# Как использовать поиск в datalist по тексту, а не по значению

Tags: html, html5, datalist

Код:

```html
    <input type="text" list="browsers">
    <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="1">fi</option >
      <option value="2">ie</option >
    </datalist>
```

Все хорошо работает, но только выполняется поиск по value, а не по тексту (те нужно чтобы по fi, ie; а не 1, 2)

Comment: у меня в `input` при вводе i выдаёт варианты fi и ie. про какой поиск идёт речь?

Comment: http://pix.my/FdvImaj2 у меня почему-то нет

Comment: перенёс ваш код в вопросе во встроенный сниппет. попробуйте в нём. вероятно, проблема либо в браузере, либо в остальном коде, который влияет на работу этого поля у вас. у меня свежий Firefox.

Comment: Да, в Firefox работает. В edge, yandex, google поиск по тексту не работает. Надо бы сделать чтобы в других браузерах тоже работало ...

Comment: разными браузерами поддерживается по-разному. так что, вероятно, без JS не обойтись

Comment: Это то ясно, но кода, реализующий это пока не нашел (только на англ вроде видел), из-за этого пишу сюда